# Here is a picture of a complex cell adhesion. I tried to segment it using the watershed algorithm, but it didn't work，can someone help me？

Tags: python, count, cell

Here is a picture of a complex cell adhesion. I tried to segment it using the watershed algorithm, but it didn't work. Can someone give me some pointers?My sincerest thanks！

Or, what other algorithms can solve such complex glued pictures?

```
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import cv2

input_img1 = cv2.imread('F:\\twf\\code\\Image enhancement\\image1\\24.png')
input_img = cv2.resize(input_img1, (0,0),fx=0.25,fy=1/3,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow("input_img",input_img)
input_imgsp=input_img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
adaptivethresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray , 255,
                                     cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,25,5)
cv2.imshow("adaptivethresh ",adaptivethresh)

#Binarization

black = np.ones([512, 512, 3], np.uint8)*255
blackb=np.ones([512, 512, 3], np.uint8)*255
__,conts, hier = cv2.findContours(adaptivethresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
l = 14.00
a = 10.00
for i, contour in enumerate(conts):
    cnt = contour
    cntArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    if cntArea <a and len < l:
        cv2.drawContours(black, conts, i, (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imshow('black',black)
blackg = cv2.cvtColor(black, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2, threshblack = cv2.threshold(blackg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
result2=adaptivethresh-threshblack
cv2.imshow('result2',result2)

#remove noise

sure_bg = cv2.dilate(result2,kernel,iterations=1)
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(result2)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=5,labels=result2)
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=result2)
output = np.zeros((input_imgsp.shape[0],input_imgsp.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
n=0
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
for label in np.unique(labels):
    if label == 0:
        continue
    mask[labels == label] = 255

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
#watershed segmentation of adherent spores

num_labels, lab, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask , connectivity=8)
output = np.zeros((input_imgsp.shape[0],input_imgsp.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
for i in range(1, num_labels):
    mask = lab == i
    output[:, :, 0][mask] = np.random.randint(0, 255)
    output[:, :, 1][mask] = np.random.randint(0, 255)
    output[:, :, 2][mask] = np.random.randint(0, 255)
cv2.namedWindow("Output", 0)
cv2.imshow('Output', output)

#Assign different colors to different connected domains
#But the result failed, and the segmentation was not successful
cv2.waitKey()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U991w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBl3t.png)